# Overriding the spring configuration file present in a jar for Junit

Tags: java, spring

I have bean definitions(x1.spring.xml) present in one of the dependency modules of my project.

Now I had to write Junit which uses x1.spring.xml file present in the jar.
I would like to override some bean entires in x1.spring.xml , so I create the same package structure in test/src --> and placed the file x1.spring.xml with my new modifications.

But when I execute the junit , program is taking the one present the jar but not the one present in
test/src folder. I maintained the same package structure as jar ( thinking it will override the one present in the jar)

Comment: How are you building your code, i.e Maven, Ant, (which) IDE?

Comment: This is just for junit execution. Nothing to do with build. All the references are in classpath.

Comment: You can't execute code you don't build, so it has plenty to do with it. What's constructing your classpath?

Comment: mvn eclipse:eclipse :)

Answer (score 2):

If you follow Maven conventions, i.e. `${basedir}/src/main/resources` and `${basedir}/src/test/resources`, then files in the latter location are put earlier in the classpath, so the `@SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` would find the test file first. It sounds like you're not using conventional directories, in which case make sure that you've configured the `resources` and `testResources` `build` elements correctly. See the [POM reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources) for details.

Or just call the test file something else to keep things simple, if this is a top level resource configured in the `@SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`.

Comment: I'm using spring 1.2.x , Legacy application , can't be changed to latest version of spring

Comment: Then you can ignore the `@SpringJunit4ClassRunner` bits (it didn't exist before 2.5), but the Maven behaviour should still hold.